# Complete Isolate vulnerable WiFi clients from rest of LAN but allow internet access (OpenWRT)

Tags: openwrt

We have 2 vulnerable WiFi devices (End of Life / Support). The connect 2 times per day via ssh or vpn to a service on the internet and perform some tasks.

Until now these devices are in the 192.168.1.X network. I would like to protect these devices as much as possible (since they won't be getting and security updates). My thought was to put these 2 devices on a OpwnWRT access point. Then I would like to isolate these clients from each other and from any other client from 192.168.1.X. I would like to allow them internet access, but deny any access from either the internet or the LAN to these clients.

Is this possible to do this using OpenWRT? Is this a sensible approach? How can I do this on Open WRT?

Comment: how does what you are proposing "protect" things better? What is the attack surface that you are intending to reduce through this action?

Comment: My worry is that potentially infected devices from the 192.168.X.X network may access the EOL vulnerable devices.